# Scala JSON Reads in Play 2.1.1

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to read a super simple piece of JSON to a Scala object:

JSON:

```
{"base": 100, "sale": 75}
```

Scala:

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Price(base: Int, sale: Option[Int])

object Price {
  implicit val priceReads = (
    (__ \ "base").read[Int] ~
    (__ \ "sale").readNullable[Int]
  )(Price)
}
```

This gives me the following error from Play:

[image]

Comment: Can you try `(Price.apply _)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  import play.api.libs.json._
  import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

  implicit val priceReads:Reads[Price] = (
    (__ \ "base").read[Int] ~
    (__ \ "sale").readNullable[Int]
  )(Price.apply _)
```

Strange that just passing case class is not working ...

Comment: I think it's because the reader is defined in the companion object.